# How the sky will change with stratospheric aerosol injections?

Tags: hard-science, environment, climate-change

The world I am designing has successfully survived the event of the almost complete depletion of natural oil reserves. By "successfully" I mean that cities are densely populated, the stock market is operational, and many countries managed to prevent anarchy. But as one might guess, the transition was very far from smooth, many critical actions had been made, including large-scale coal burning for energy generation, which resulted in the rapid acceleration of global warming.

[Stratospheric aerosol injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratospheric_aerosol_injection) are a temporary solution for some symptoms of global warming. The following picture from Wikipedia gives a good summary of this process.

[image]

An important detail that is left out by this picture is that the injection is most effective if performed along the equator.

I am interested in the view from the deck of a ship that tries to hide from satellites under **thick** clouds that are, hopefully, created during this process.

I know that there is a process called ["marine cloud brightening"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_cloud_brightening) that literally creates clouds above the ocean, but, as I understand, it only helps a little to fight climate change. It can't fully mitigate the acceleration of global warming that my world is going through.

EDIT:

Removed subquestions.

Comment: If you read to the "Uncertainties" and "Other possible side effects" sections of the article you have linked, it seems that the answer to the first and third subquestions is "we don't know", which makes it impossible to definitively answer any of the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All information comes from the Kurzgesagt video, "[Geoengineering: A Horrible Idea We Might Have to Do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSu5sXmsur4)". They do a much better job at explaining what I am about to attempt.

To answer your subquestions(You should only ask one question per post):

1. SAI would create clouds. This is because clouds reflect the solar radiation that is causing the planet to warm.
2. The clouds would probably be white with a slight tint to the color of the aerosols.
3. I'm not sure how long the clouds will be in the atmosphere. I guess it depends on the climate and air currents.
4. On the coasts, if used for extended periods of time, the ocean will fall. That is if the oceans had rises because of the warming planet.
5. The interior is a different story. We don't fully understand how SAIs will affect local areas. It could catastrophically alter rainfall patterns, leaving entire sections with little precipitation. This could cause massive droughts and famines across the planet.

Hope this helped! I recommend watching the video and going to Kurzgesagt's [sources page](https://sites.google.com/view/sourcesgeoengineering).

Comment: @JBH Sorry, I did add the sentence at the beginning but that isn't enough, I understand. I just knew how to answer the question and didn't think too much about it.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I knew about the video, but I forgot that Kurzgesagt provides sources.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly No problem. Happy to help.